# Android-Market bugs?

Tags: android, google-play

i've got a problem with an app that i published 2 days ago.

The app still doesn't appear in the market within the new entries 
(appear only with direct link)

About 1 month ago, I've uploaded a previous version of that app..with 
the same name and a different package name. 
It was a beta so i disabled it in the console and i uploaded a NEW app 
with the same name but different package name...This can be related 
with the problems mentioned before?

Anybody had similar problems?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience it won't last near the top for very long at all. after 2 days you'd probably have to scroll down pretty far to find yours. I have noticed that sometimes my apps show up in the new list within a few minutes of uploading, and sometimes not for an hour or so. But I've never witnessed it happen any longer.

As for whether or not changing your package name could result in your problem. Perhaps, but I wouldn't think so. In general though you should strive to never change your package name. This will result in users having to un-install before they are able to install new versions.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that is the new Google design.  You don't get your app listed in the new
category (or any other) unless it's already a high-ranking app before
it's launched, or, you are one of the top-rated developers.